# Note Recovery Alternatives

Tags: macos, icloud, notes.app, data-recovery

It appears that by switching iCloud accounts on my MacBook, ALL the notes stored in Notes.app have disappeared/been deleted. These notes were not synced with iCloud -- and Time Machine was disabled.

I understand that there's a possibility that these notes still exist somewhere on my Mac HD.

Where would I look for these notes? How can I restore them?

Comment: what does it say in Note Preferences, default account ? On my mac or icloud

Comment: @Buscar, "On My Mac."

Comment: then you should be fine, Notes are kept for 30 days after Delete. Look in the Recently Deleted folder (in Notes)

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a "recently deleted" section in notes.app.

Comment: Use Folder view

Comment: Still no recently deleted section.

Answer (score 1):

they should be in the

~/Library/Containers/com.apple.Notes/Data/Library/Notes/

suggested settings to keep a copy on your hard drive

[image]

Comment: Adding the .html ending to the NotesV7.storedata files, I get "RçR¯Ò€ÒÈÒœÒÂÒ¦ÒQ¥ãK'ö?Uþ_x tù¯têÿ." Shouldn't I be able to read this? Does this mean that the notes have been overwritten?

Comment: what is the size of the file

Comment: There are 4:
NotesV6.storedata 0;
NotesV7.storedata 156 KB;
NotesV7.storedata-shm 33 KB;
NotesV7.storedata-wal 214 KB.

Comment: It looks like you deleted it, mine is 2.5 MB, and I can open it in Text Edit

Comment: I didn't -- they disappeared after I switched iCloud accounts. I watched it happen. Does this mean that I'm out of luck? I even opted to keep a copy of all documents, contacts, photos, etc. when prompted via System Preferences -> iCloud.